# Adding character to timestamp

Tags: java

I am currently stuck on an issue with renaming files.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileRename {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {

        File folder = new File("x:\\chadhold\\test\\");

        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        if(listOfFiles != null){

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                    File f = new File("x:\\chadhold\\test\\"+listOfFiles[i].getName());
                    String currentName = f.getName();            
                    currentName = currentName.replace(".D**************", ".D******.T********");
                    f.renameTo(new File("x:\\chadhold\\test\\" + currentName));
                   // f.renameTo(new File("x:\\chadhold\\test\\" +currentName.substring(0, currentName.lastIndexOf("."))));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("conversion is done");
    }
}
```

So what i am trying to do here is find files that start with .D
These files are end with a timestamp which is why i am using ***** because each file will be named differently.

I need to put a .T and remove the last 2 characters from the file names.

Hopefully i explained this good enough!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include sample input/output names.

Comment: You can use foo.startsWith(".D") to find appropriate strings, and then use .substring to get portions of a String to concatenate back together.

Comment: AFK0281.EETM.D1TWP015-02.20170208200225253=>
AFK0281.EETM.D1TWP015-02.D170208.T200225253

Comment: It looks like what you really want to do is replace the last section of the filename (delimited by a .) with a D{date}.T{time}, right?

Comment: Yes correct @DomenicD.

Comment: Minor comment- strings are immutable, so a replace return would be a new object

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the replace method on the string, you'd be better off making a method that parses the filename and returns a new one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(newFileName("AFK0281.EETM.D1TWP015-02.20170208200225253"));
}

private static String newFileName(String currentName) {
    String[] parts = currentName.split("\\.");
    String last = parts[parts.length - 1];
    parts[parts.length - 1] = "D" + last.substring(2, 8) + ".T" + last.substring(9);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : parts) {
        sb.append(s).append(".");
    }
    String newName = sb.toString();
    return newName.substring(0, newName.length() - 1);
}
```

Output is

> AFK0281.EETM.D1TWP015-02.D170208.T200225253

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not much of a java developer. Could you make the adjustments to my code provided?

Comment: just replace where you were doing the replace with `currentName = newFileName(currentName)`

Comment: StringUtils cannot be resolved.
I appreciate you helping me btw.

Comment: You would have needed to add it as a dependency. I updated the code to not have that dependency. It's not pretty though.

Comment: Not exactly. I guess you are a newb. ;) https://hastebin.com/keyeqobipe.vbs

Comment: Yes big noob haha, Now im getting this error http://i.imgur.com/9SUnYku.png

Comment: sure. Would appreciate it if you'd accept the answer.